# Passing entities with Luis to FormFlow

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding, formflow

I'm using Luis to recognize if the user starts the flow with some entities, for example: he can say "*Report*" or "*I want to report in London*" or "*I want to report place x in London*"

```
    [LuisIntent("Report")]
    public async Task ReportCompleteIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        EntityRecommendation location;
        EntityRecommendation POS;

        result.TryFindEntity("Weather.Location", out location);
        result.TryFindEntity("POS", out POS);

        //I tried with passing entities (it doesn't recognize the entities in formBuild)
        context.Call(Chain.From(() => new FormDialog<OutOfStockReport>(new OutOfStockReport(), buildForm: OutOfStockReport.BuildForm, options: FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities: result.Entities)), OOSDialogComplete);
        //Also tried prepopulating the state
        context.Call(Chain.From(() => new FormDialog<OutOfStockReport>(new OutOfStockReport() { LocalizationId = location?.Entity }, buildForm: OutOfStockReport.BuildForm, options: FormOptions.PromptInStart)), OOSDialogComplete);
    }
```

This is the class and the buildform:

```
[Serializable]
[Template(TemplateUsage.NavigationFormat, "{&}")]
public class OutOfStockReport
{
    public string LocalizationId;
    public string PositionId;     

    public static IForm<OutOfStockReport> BuildForm()
    {
        return FormBuilderHelper.CreateCustomForm<OutOfStockReport>()
            .Message("Welcome!")         
            .Field(new FieldReflector<OutOfStockReport>(nameof(LocalizationId))
                .SetType(null)
                .SetActive(hasLocation)
                .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                {
                    var cities = new City().GetCities();

                    foreach (var option in cities)
                    {
                        var description = new DescribeAttribute($"{option.Name}", message: $"{option.Name}", title: $"{option.Name}");
                        field.AddDescription(option.Id, description);
                        field.AddTerms(option.Id, Language.GenerateTerms(Language.CamelCase(option.Name), 3));
                    }

                    return true;
                })
                .SetValidate(async (state, response) =>
                {
                    state.PositionId = null;

                    var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = response };

                    return result;

                }))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<OutOfStockReport>(nameof(PositionId))
                .SetType(null)
                .SetActive((state) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.LocalizationId))
                .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                {
                    field.RemoveValues();

                    var localizedOptions = new Position().GetPositions(state.LocalizationId);

                    foreach (var option in localizedOptions)
                    {
                        var description = new DescribeAttribute($"{option.Name}", message: $"{option.Name}", title: $"{option.Name}");
                        field.AddDescription(option.Id, description);
                        field.AddTerms(option.Id, Language.GenerateTerms(Language.CamelCase($"{option.Id} {option.Name} {option.Direction}"), 3));
                    }

                    return true;
                }))
            .AddRemainingFields()       
            .Confirm("Are you sure of your selection?{||}")
            .OnCompletion(async (context, state) => await context.PostAsync($"Thanks, the task is complete."))                    
            .Build();
```

If adding an *ActiveDelegate hasLocation* I can control if the field *LocationId* must be shown or not. This works but after that the bot breaks with "*Sorry, my bot code is having an issue*"

Example with wrong text
[image: example with wrong text]

Example with right text
[image: example with right text]

EDIT

The classes that are used in the form:

Class BaseModel

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Class City

```
public class City : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Class Position

```
public class Position : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the full entity list or you want to fill the form with the entity you received from luis?

Comment: The ideal would be to pass luis entities to the formflow as responses (to use native formflow validation and functionality) but i don't know if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to parse the Luis result and get the entity value from the result and pass the result to formflow.

**LuisDialog**

```
[LuisIntent("Report")]
public async Task ReportCompleteIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
        OutOfStockReport form = new OutOfStockReport();
        EntityRecommendation location;
        EntityRecommendation POS;

        if(result.TryFindEntity("Weather.Location", out location))
        {
        //Here you are initializing the form with values.
        //If you have written any validation code for this field then
        //formflow will check the validation when the form is called

             form.Location = location.Entity;
        }
        if(result.TryFindEntity("POS", out POS))
        {
             form.POS = POS.Entity;
        }

        context.Call(form,OutOfStockReport.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart,OOSDialogComplete);

}
```

If you have to process the Entity before assigning it to the field in formflow you will have to do it in the Luis Dialog method itself.

Comment: it isn't possibile to make the dialog processing the entities like how he would do 
regularly if the user insert it one to one?

Comment: could you explain what you are receiving in luis and what you are filling in the form?

Comment: For example, luis receives "*I want to report in London*" and passes *London* to the FormFlow. Luis can't know if the city is right or less and the form flow needs the Id of the city for continue (The form knows that *London* is the description and populates that field with the id). The field for the city uses a class *City*, that has a *Name* and an *Id*, for populate the options.

Comment: So if I understand, the entities go straight into the state without any kind of binding or validation like FormFlow would run in case of a user answer. 
So while normally "London" would be validated and end up registered as an ID in LocalizationId, when passing a prepopulated state LocalizationId ends up being just "London". Am I right?
I don't know if it's possible to achieve that kind of behaviour. @AnitaGeorge

Comment: @StubbornElio What is your city class like?

Comment: @StubbornElio Are you retrieving the values from the database? .. i got a workaround with enums ..

Comment: @Imartin yes it is not possible. I am trying find an alternative method

Comment: @AnitaGeorge yes the values are from the database. For the moment the values are validated before sending them to the FormFlow and now it works. It would be good use the validator of the FormFlow, as it is now is like write the same code two times.